# Use PFUser on Parse without a Username

Tags: ios, parse-platform, backend

I'm building an app where emails are supposed to be the main identifiers. I don't want my users to have a username at all. I'm using Parse for backend and want to use the PFUser class for user signups etc. It seems like PFUser requires a username. Is there anyway to use PFUser without using username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am in the same situation as you, but what I do is just set the email address my user enters for the username field. Now they can just login with their email address :)

Comment: Cool! Thank you! That sounds like it would work perfectly. Any known issues with this? How do you do get email confirmations though?

Comment: @AsadJamalMalik No issues for me, works perfectly :) Just be careful with cases because it will be case sensitive. I also use the email field for email confirmations, so both the username and email fields have the email the user entered.

Comment: Very nice. Will get the job done for me right now. But if you find a more "proper" solution which can also solve the case sensitive issue, let me know. Thanks again :)

Comment: @AsadJamalMalik You can just make everything lowercase after they enter it and you're good! No problem, glad I could help! :) Would you mind marking my answer as correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can set `emailAsUsername` to `true` in `signUpView` as following:

```
signUpViewController.signUpView.emailAsUsername = true
```

Comment: Please elaborate more.